# How do I get a remote source to work with an autocomplete?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Is it possible to add an autocomplete in a google spreadsheet script with a remote source? 
Below is one of my attempts to do so but I have no idea where to go from here (I am a newb to google scripts):

```
function my_autocomplete(){
  var list = ['dog','doog'];
  var app = UiApp.createApplication();
  var suggestBox = SuggestBoxCreator.createSuggestBox(app,'autocompleter',200,list);
  app.add(suggestBox);
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  doc.show(app);
}
```

I've googled my heart out but can't find a single example of an autocomplete with a remote source that is compatible with Google Scripts...is it even possible?

(I don't have to use/modify the autocomplete example I have above, so if there's another approach I'm all ears! thx!)

Comment: Why did you remove the reference in your question?  It was the very same link given in the accepted answer... btw I really don't see how it answers your question....but that's your choice :-)

Comment: Serge it wasnt the same link. It had a so link. My answer is a link I googled based on the posted code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google suggestboxcreator and you will find this https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/learn-by-example/uiapp-examples-code-snippets/suggest-box. Use that library, thou  it does the search server side. Make one with htmservice and do it client side so its faster. Write the selected value into the active cell of the active spreadsheet.